# Flutter "NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method 'where' was called on null." Error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a code like this:

```
List ProductsList;
//...
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _firestore.collection("Products").snapshots().listen((event) {
    setState(() {
      ProductsList = event.docs;
    });
  });
}
//...
StreamBuilder(
  stream: ProductsList.where((x) => x["Name"] == SearchText).toList().first, // Filter
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Card(
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["Name"]),
            ),
          );
        },
      );
    } else {
      return Text("No data");
    }
  }
),
```

My aim is to fetch the `Name` value from the Arrays in the list. But when I run the code I get an error like this:

[image]

I tested it and the results are in the list. How can I to solve the problem? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ProductsList variable is declared, but not defined. You set the ProductList in the listener in initState, but it only gets set if a change is made in your Products Collection. This is why it can't call the .where on ProductList, because it's null after the initState.

You either give ProductsList a default Value

```
List ProductList = [];
```

or you pass the stream into the StreamBuilder and change your logic inside the builder

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: _firestore.collection("Products").snapshots(),
```

Comment: Hello. I tried pulling the search system directly from Firestore but I couldn't. That's why I tried making it on the list. Since it is not possible to search by pulling from Firestore, I have to do it from the list. Your answer worked, thanks. But a new error has occurred. The error is: `StateError (Bad state: No element)`

Comment: What do you mean by search system and search by pulling from Firestore?

Comment: In the docs i can pass the firestore stream to the StreamBuilder, check this out: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#realtime-changes

Comment: Yes, I want to search Firestore by pulling data. Actually, I was able to make the system, but the search system did not work correctly due to case sensitive. I thought I could `.toLowerCase()` the ones in the list.

Comment: Do you have an opinion on this matter?